# Is there a way to convert stdin/stdout fds into one fd?

Tags: linux, sockets, openssl, file-descriptor

I want to process SSL from stdin, and send SSL out stdout, but OpenSSL accepts only one file descriptor in the set fd call:

```
SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);
```

Is there a way to combine the stdin and stdout file descriptors into one?

I realize I can make a process that just reads from stdin/out and writes to the file descriptor, but I was trying to think of a way to avoid that extra processing layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want to use SSL_set_rfd() and SSL_set_wfd(). From [the manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/SSL_set_fd.html):

> SSL_set_rfd() and SSL_set_wfd() perform the respective action, but
>   only for the read channel or the write channel, which can be set
>   independently.